# Как разделить панель разработчика в браузере

Tags: браузер, ide, dom

Отделить отладку от DOM-а. Я начинающий в вебе, так что можно с примером IDE - там точно должна быть решена эта задача.

**Обновление**

Отладчик и инспектор соответственно - если в мозилле.
Elements, Sources - в хроме.

Возможно легче просто перейти на IDE, но для простой верстки - допилки мне хватало инструментов браузера.

Сейчас появилась необходимость отладки - но это не так удобно в браузере.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, что в вашем понимании отладка и что такое DOM?
Что-то форма отправки ответа сломалась. ((

Comment: @tigmaz, вам надо сделать так, чтобы можно было одновременно открыть две вкладки из инструментов разработчика?